# Is it possible to test a security group policy that restricts S3 access only to a single VPC without creating an EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc

Title is pretty self explanatory, I want to lockdown S3 access to only be allowed from a particular VPC. Is there a way of doing this without creating an EC2 to test it?

Comment: Well, if you really want to verify it, you need something with an ENI in that network - a Lambda function in a VPC should work as well, otherwise Marcins answer covers everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to lockdown S3 access to only be allowed from a particular VPC

AWS docs have entire chapter devoted to limiting access to S3 to a given VPC or VPC endpoint:

- [Controlling access from VPC endpoints with bucket policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies-vpc-endpoint.html)

But if you apply these bucket policies, you will actually **lock yourself out of the bucket**. So you will have to use EC2 instance or some other way of accessing the bucket from within the VPC. Any other access will not be allowed.

Comment: @Sheen How did it go? Did you manage to create a bucket policy that restrict access to your bucket?

Comment: Yes, the bucket policy was fine, it had already been created before asking this question. It was more an exercise in whether it was possible to do it without an EC2.